# Pull MessageTrace data from O365 RestUri

Tags: powershell, office365api

I'm trying to record Message delivery/failure information in O365. I have over 250K mailboxes and the message I'm trying to trace is a global email sent to a root DL with lots of nested DLs.
I'm trying the below piece.

```
$Root = "https://reports.office365.com/ecp/reportingwebservice/reporting.svc/" 
$Format = "`$format=JSON"
$WebService = "MessageTrace"
$Select = "`$select=RecipientAddress,Status"
$Filter = "`$filter=MessageId eq 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@xxxx.xxx.xxxx.OUTLOOK.COM' and Status eq 'Failed'"

# Build report URL
$url = ($Root + $WebService + "/?" + $Select + "&" + $Filter + "&" + $Format)
$sens = $null

Do {
    $sens = Invoke-RestMethod -Credential $cred -uri $url
    $sens.d.results.Count
    $sens.d.results | select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty RecipientAddress| ft -Wrap

    if ($sens.d.__next) {
        $url = ($sens.d.__next + "&" + $Format)
    }
} While ($sens.d.__next -ne $null)
```

For sample message trace in my test domain, I should have:

- 19 Delivered eventd
- 14 Expanded events
- 5001 Failed events.

I hit a problem with `PageSize` as the default limit is `2000`. Filter with Delivered & Expanded gives me accurate results as it’s completed on the first iteration.

But Failed events, as it has to break into 3 pages, is not fetching the data correctly.

If my understanding is correct, I should see 2 iterations with 2000 entries each and with `__next` containing `$skiptoken=1999` and `3999` respectively and the last iteration with 1001 entries without `__next` but I keep getting `__next` even after the 3rd iteration and the `$skiptoken` keeps increasing over 10000s.

It seems to be looping with the same results.

```
2000
sens2500@contoso.local
2000
sens939@contoso.local
2000
sens1183@contoso.local
2000
sens214@contoso.local
2000
sens1183@contoso.local
2000
sens1423@contoso.local
```

I could see the results entries are not unique between 1st, 2nd, and 3rd iterations either. It seems like it just pulls a random 2000 entries on each attempt.

I tried to do an `[IN]` with `$OrderBy=RecipientAddress` to see if that makes any difference but I wasn't able to make it work successfully.

Any help on this?

Comment: Have you tried using the [`Get-MessageTrace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/get-messagetrace?view=exchange-ps) cmdlet instead?

Comment: Thanks Marc. Yes, I did try Get-MessageTrace. It's pretty good when the recipient count is less. When it's over 100K, it takes long time, gets throttled and eventually gets timed out.

Comment: @Sens, did you find a solution to this? I'm in a similar situation. Where did you get the d.__next from?